# flex-basis not working as expected

Tags: css, flexbox

As i understand flex-basis is responsible for deciding the size of an element.

In the example below, I am trying to size all boxes equally to 100px.
Just using flex-basis is not achieving the effect.

```
.each_box {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;

  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100px;

  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;

  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LvrrzHWIw1tPGwK05bCU

Answer (score 21):

I found I had to use min-width as well as flex-basis in Chrome. I'm not sure if I had another problem that caused this.

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

[Priority: `max-width|min-width`>`flex-basis(not content)`>`width`>`flex-basis:max-content`](https://juejin.cn/post/6844904016439148551#heading-8)

Comment: I had same problem in Firefox. flex-basic is completely ignored, and as the matter a fact, I just use min-width and max-width.. I don't see the need for flex-basic alltogether

Comment: I had the same issue and that solved this. Is this a bug in chrome?

Comment: Be sure to check the answer by dholbert. flex-basis works correctly when it is a child of display:flex. display:flex is only active for children of the container that sets such a display characteristic.

Answer (score 10):

Be sure to also add: `flex-wrap: wrap;`  because the default value `nowrap` in order to fit everything in one line can affect the size of the elements (eg: width, flex-basis, etc..).

Comment: This is the correct answer not the one that's currently highlighted...

Answer (score 8):

The `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis` properties only have an effect on elements *in a flex container* -- i.e. elements whose parent has `display:flex`.

You need to put your `each_box` divs directly inside of a `display:flex` element for them to honor their flex-related properties.

Specifically, your markup looks like this (from right clicking one of the yellow divs + hitting "inspect" in Firefox):

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- ngRepeat: stock in stockList -->
  <div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="stock in stockList">
    <div class="each_box ng-binding">
    0-FB/100
```

You've got `container` styled as `display:flex`, but that does no good for your `each_box` elements, because they're grandchildren, separated from the flex container by the `display:block` ng-scope.

So you either need to get rid of the `ng-scope` wrapper, or make it also have `display:flex`.

Comment: This was the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add a width: `width:100px;`
`flex-basis` gives a default proportion, which will then grow or shrink.

Comment: I want to avoid using width.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `width` (you can also use `min-width` or `max-width` if needed)? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569229/what-exactly-flex-basis-property-sets)

Comment: Using an explicit width defeats the purpose of using flexbox.. The box is no longer flexible.

Comment: @Roy the OP asks for setting fixed width when using flex. What you want to achieve is have flex handle spacing/sizing as well.

Answer (score 0):

All works for me:

```
.flex-child { width:0; }
```

AND

```
.flex-child { min-width:0; }
```

AND

```
.flex-child { flex-shrink:0; } /* no scrollbars inside */
```