# Flex-basis 0% behaviour

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to understand `flex-basis`. If `flex-basis` is auto then it means set initial width to the min-content and then apply `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` according to the ratio i.e. If each item has `flex: 1 1 auto`, and the initial width of each item is 93px, 93px and 83px respectively. If there is some extra space in the parent then it calculates extra space, divide it into 3 portions, and then grows each item accordingly by adding one portion. If the parent is small, then it shrinks by subtracting one portion.

If `flex-basis` is set to 0%, then does it divides the entire width of the parent into the 3 portions and assign each portion to each item? If `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` is set to 0 then they get the defined width.

Is this right, if not please explain using the mathematical example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly flex-basis property sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569229/what-exactly-flex-basis-property-sets)

Comment: No, it doesn't explain my question. I understand the behaviour in case of fixed width, what I am not getting how the elements width is decided by what ratio in case of flex basis auto and 0%